# How to pass options to RPM through YUM CLI?

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm

I would like to pass the --excludepath option to RPM through YUM since YUM doesn't provide an option like that. The --excludepath option tells the rpm command to exclude all files that start with the given path.

Comment: Note that you can edit the repository files to exclude certain packages from being downloaded and installed, if your goal is to maintain your own versions of certain programs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're out of luck if you want to use `yum`.  That's not a feature the yum package supports.  `yum` uses a subset of all the features provided by the `rpm` command.  (It actually uses a python module rpmUtils rather than calling `rpm` directly.)

Answer (score 1):

man 5 yum.conf:

> tsflags      Comma or space separated list of transaction flags to pass to the rpm transaction set. These include 'noscripts', 'notriggers', 'nodocs', 'test', 'justdb' and 'nocontexts'. 'repackage' is also available but that does nothing with newer rpm versions. You can set all/any of them. However, if you don't know what these do in the context of an rpm transaction set you're best leaving it alone. Default is an empty list.

To do this on the command-line, use `--setopt=` feature. Here is an example of how to remove the `ipset-service` package without triggering the uninstall/pre-un scriptlets (which checks if iptables depends on it):

```
yum remove --setopt=tsflags=noscripts,notriggers ipset-service
```